# Ramda Pipe throws TypeError: Cannot read property of 'length' undefined

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a curried function where my `pipe` is delaying its execution until parameters are passed in.

The following implementation throws `TypeError: Cannot read property of 'length' of undefined`:

```
export const stageGenerator =
  pipe(
    createStage,
    buildStage,
  );

//////// import stageGenerator in different file ///////////

const stageMapper = flowType => {
  if (stage) return stageGenerator

const result = stageMapper('asdf')
```

but the following implementation works

```
export const stageGenerator = () =>
  pipe(
    createStage,
    buildStage,
  );

//////// import stageGenerator in different file ///////////

const stageMapper = flowType => {
  if (stage) return stageGenerator()

const result = stageMapper('asdf')
```

On top of that, piping the function manually like so works:

```
const stageGenerator = (params) => buildStage(createStage(params))
```

In both cases I pass the same parameters to `stageMapper`. When I console.log the type of stageMapper when I call it, it would say `function`.

However, when I change the pipe function to:

```
export const stageGenerator =
  pipe(
    tap(x => console.log(x)),
    createStage,
    buildStage,
  );
```

it will throw `TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` when calling `stageMapper`.

Why am I getting those errors? Is it an erroneous function call with JavaScript, or is it the wrong implementation of pipe?

Comment: () => means arrow function.

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

```
() => pipe(createStage, buildStage);
```

is a function consisting of a single operation, calling pipe with the specified parameters and returning a result. So, `stageGenerator` is a function. Without `() =>` `stageGenerator` would be a value, the one returned by pipe.
 Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: The reason I want to not call the arrow function is to take advantage of Ramda's point-free notation (http://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/06/21/thinking-in-ramda-pointfree-style/). Does this mean that JavaScript will not interpret the declaration of `stageGenerator` as a point-free function, but rather as a value where `pipe` was given undefined parameters?

Comment: @user1636937 since you observe different behavior in the two cases I think we can conclude that that's the case indeed.

Answer (score 0):

In both examples, you never actually call `stageGenerator`:

```
export const stageGenerator =
  pipe(
    createStage,
    buildStage,
  );

//////// import stageGenerator in different file ///////////

const stageMapper = flowType => {
  if (stage) return stageGenerator
```

`pipe` creates a function so `stageGenerator` is a function which you need to call with some arguments:

```
const stageMapper = flowType => {
  if (stage) return stageGenerator(stage);
  //...
}
```

In the second example, `stageGenerator` is a function that returns another function (the result from `pipe`)

```
export const stageGenerator = () =>
  pipe(
    createStage,
    buildStage,
  );

//////// import stageGenerator in different file ///////////

const stageMapper = flowType => {
  if (stage) return stageGenerator()
```

But this is still the same issue: you still need to call it with some arguments:

```
const stageMapper = flowType => {
  if (stage) return stageGenerator()(stage);
  //...
}
```

---

This is probably not what you meant anyway:

```
const stageGenerator = () =>
  pipe(createStage, buildStage);
```

This is a function that returns another function. Unless you pass it some parameters to execute it directly as shown here:

```
const stageGenerator = (params) =>
  pipe(createStage, buildStage)
    (params);
```

Then you may as well simplify it and do:

```
const stageGenerator = pipe(createStage, buildStage);
```

Don't forget to call it with some parameters though ;)

Comment: thanks for your comments. I realized I wasn't very descriptive in my original post so I made some edits to clarify some things. I also made typo in the original post for `buildStage(createStage(params))`

Comment: I have reviewed your edit but my answer still stands. Your error must come from something else. Can you post the full `stageMapper` function please?